# background-image doesn't work in foreach loop

Tags: laravel, foreach, background-image

I have a foreach loop and slider, and into loop I have background image. Background image is working for some, but not all of them.

This is my code:

```
@if($products)
@foreach($products as $product)
       <div class="swiper-slide text-center">
           <a href="{{url('products/'.$product->id)}}">
                <div class="border-2"
                  style="background-image: url({{src($product,'main_image')}})"></div>
                <div class="mt-1">{{$product->title}}</div>
              </a>
        </div>
@endforeach
@endif
```

src is a function

```
function src($object,$slug,$thumb_size = null) {
$table = $object->getTable();
$width =  ($thumb_size)?explode('/',$thumb_size)[0]:false;
$height = ($thumb_size)?explode('/',$thumb_size)[1]:false;

if($attachment = $object->attachments($slug)->first()) {
    if($width && $height) {
        $src = url("/uploads/".$table."/thumb_{$width}-{$height}_".$attachment->file);
    } else {
        $src = url("/uploads/".$table."/".$attachment->file);
    }
} else {
    if($width && $height) {
        if(file_exists("uploads/defaults/thumb_{$width}-{$height}_default.png")) {
            $src = url('')."/uploads/defaults/thumb_{$width}-{$height}_default.png";
        } else {
            Image::make("default.png")->fit($width,$height)->save("uploads/defaults/thumb_{$width}-{$height}_default.png");
            $src = url('')."/uploads/defaults/thumb_{$width}-{$height}_default.png";
        }
    } else {
        $src = url('')."/default.png";
    }
}

return $src;
```

}

Comment: what this return to you? `src($product,'main_image')`
We need more data :)

Comment: src is a function

Comment: But what does the function return? Show an example. Or just screenshot the dom with the attribute in it. Also - what is the console error?

Comment: doesn't show my image, and background image has line on itself int inspect element.